# pgAdmin 4 error in creating a new server. (could not connect to server: connection refused)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have downloaded postgreSQL version 11.1 on my MacBook version 10.14.2, while installing I got an error says the following:
" **Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly The database cluster initialization failed.**" and then clicked on next. *(Mentioned this, just in case if it is related to my problem)*

The problem I have now is, I can't view anything under servers, and whenever I try to create a new server it shows me this message.
[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnzLD.png)

I'm new to this and don't know what to do, any idea what should be done?

Comment: Yes the cluster initialization failed message is related. For the server to be able to start the cluster needs to be initialized. This can be done by running [initdb -D datadir](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html) manually. However I do not know what would normally be used as datadir on a mac. When that is succesful you can start the server with `pg_ctl start -D datadir`

Comment: I'm not sure why nothing works. I have looked into the website, but still. Thank you Eelke.